# Can we get only specific column from a table using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, projection

I have to fetch data from a table having 100 columns, how can I implement this without creating pojo of all the fields using Spring JPA?

Comment: You could make use of @Query technique of querying the table, only taking the specific columns to the result entity pojo

Comment: I have tried to get the specific columns by using @Query and have used Entity class having only those specific fields but I am getting exception mentioned below  - could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: can paste your code in the question, its likely the pojo you created didn't match the column name, or in your select SQL you used the SQL column instead of the pojo attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Interface-based Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces), create interface with only the attributes required and write abstract method in repository to return interface, for example

> A projection interface to retrieve a firstname and lastname attributes

```
interface NamesOnly {

 String getFirstname();
 String getLastname();
}
```

> A repository using an interface based projection with a query method

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, UUID> {

  Collection<NamesOnly> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create pojo of 100 fields in this case? In the example mentioned by you Person is the object which I am going to get with 100 attributes.So I guess I have to include the pojo of it.

Answer (score 0):

Such queries sometimes called scalar queries. Basically you will need to write a native query and help Hibernate what fields you are getting. Here are few links that explain the issue:

1. [Hibernate Tip: Best Way To Work with Scalar Projections](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-best-way-scalar-projections/),
2. [Native Queries – How to call native SQL queries with JPA & Hibernate](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-native-queries/),
3. [Hibernate’s addScalar() Method](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-addscalar)